# Is it 'express shipped' or 'shipped express'?

Tags: verbs, word-order, past-tense, compounds

Which one is correct?

> - He should have express shipped it to me.
> - He should have it shipped express to me.

Comment: I believe both are correct.

Comment: What are the possible grammar issues?  I'm looking for the British standard.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted?  I wrote it in the same manner I have seen accepted here on the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can parse *he should have express shipped* is to regard *express shipped* as the past of a compound verb *express ship* (which I would hyphenate). This is perfectly understandable, but it is not, as far as I know, an established word or phrase, so I would not use that form in any formal context.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. In the first case, to *express ship* is a set phrase, as we might say to *green light*. In the second, *express* gives the method of shipping, as we might say to *fly first-class*.

Such verbs cannot arbitrarily be inverted, however; in fact, I have a hard time thinking of another that can be, from *air drying* my mushrooms (but not *drying my mushrooms air*) to *zebra striping* my spreadsheet (but not *striping my spreadsheet zebra*).

Comment: If I want to say the method of the shipping used then which one would be correct?

Comment: Which one is the verb?  Shipped or express?  I'm poor at grammar.

Comment: @verve If you say *express shipped*, then *express shipped* is the verb. If you say *shipped express*, then *shipped* is the verb and *express* an adverb. To describe the method of shipping, you could say *express* or *express shipping*.